Can the initial splash screen image be omitted if I have a slash screen defined in the index.html page?
I have a React app that is converted to an android app via Capacitor.
Capacitor uses an initial launch splash screen that is displayed before the index.html page is rendered.
I am wondering if the index.html page can be the very first UI displayed when the app launches?
If possible, how do I remove the default initial slash screen?
